# WordPress: save output of do_action in variable

Tags: wordpress, function, hook, action

I want to save the output of do_action in a variable to use it later.
How could I save these output?

Comment: explain more with your functions here

Comment: I have these actions from a plugin and want to use the output of the actions in a shortcode

Comment: see, do_action is a hook where you are attaching a function(callback). And if the callback is really returning something then you can just call it. 
e.g. do_action('init','your_function');   then you can simply call $x = your_function(). But what if the function is not returning anything ? may be you need to modify them. But if it is by other plugin it is not supposed to be edited, instead you can use start_ob. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your comment. unfortunately I didn't get it... ;) I have to find another way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use ob_start() and ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean() see example #1 on the following page in the PHP manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-contents.php

It looks scary the first time, but it works well. Just make sure to always use ob_end_clean() for every time you use ob_start()

```
ob_start(); // start capturing output.
do_action('any_action_you_want');
$save_output_here = ob_get_contents(); // the actions output will now be stored in the variable as a string!
ob_end_clean(); // never forget this or you will keep capturing output.
```

Comment: You have a typo in your answer. Please change "ob_get_content()" to "ob_get_contents()"