# Store do_action() in var and continue execution

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm training on the creation / modification of wordpress plugin, to do this, I need to make a simple PHP script that performs different actions. The problem is that once the `do_action` is called, nothing happens.

```php
<?php

[...]

$actions_to_do = [
  'wp_ajax_lorem_ipsum'
];


foreach ($actions_to_do as $action) {
  $output = do_action($action);
  echo $output;
}
```

I've seen :

- [Are there any drawback of using output buffer on do_action function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47255378/are-there-any-drawback-of-using-output-buffer-on-do-action-function)
- [WordPress: save output of do_action in variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723513/wordpress-save-output-of-do-action-in-variable)

And tried this trick with the ob_start() but the problem remains the same.

```php
foreach ($actions_to_do as $action) {
  ob_start();
  do_action($action);
  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  echo $output;
}
```

I specify that in the state I do not test with a plugin in particular because the problem is the same whatever the plugin or the action

Answer (score 0):

Think of do_action() as a placeholder for a possible action. Here is simple example to illustrate it:

```
<?php
// You can paste this in page.php, in header of footer, or any other place that would be easy to observe (for test purpose only!)

echo "Hello";
do_action( 'hello_name' ); 
echo "!";
?>
```

By simply placing this code and opening a corresponding page you will be presented with:

```
Hello!
```

While do_action() was executed, there were no actions associated with it.

Now without removing existing code, add the following to your functions.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * We register a custom action which will be processed by 
 * WordPress when do_action( 'hello_name' ) is executed.
 */
function my_name_is() {
    echo "Tom";
}
add_action( 'hello_name', 'my_name_is' );
?>
```

Reloading the page should now display:

```
Hello Tom!
```

You may register multiple actions to be triggered when do_action( 'hello_name' ) function is executed using add_action() function.